# OnFocusChangeListener listen for background click

Tags: android

I have one `EditText` in my Activity. `OnFocusChangeListener` is only called when another `EditText` (or input) is selected.

How can I determinate a click outside of my `EditText` (like jQuerys `blur` does)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to listen to root layout click...If your `EditText` is in `LinearLayout`, give the `LinearLayout` some `id` and listen to `LinearLayout` `OnClickListener`..